# How i can get TFS WorkItem and his children WorkItems(not WorkItemReference) in one trip from TFS on .net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I have a trouble like this guy: [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748412/retrieving-work-items-and-their-linked-work-items-in-a-single-query-using-the-tf)

I can get only WorkItemReference with Wiql help.

```
var query = new Wiql
                {
                 Query = string.Format("SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State]" +
                                      " FROM WorkItems" +
                                     $" WHERE [System.Id] IN ({ids})" +
                                      " ORDER BY [System.Id]")
                };
WorkItemQueryResult queryResult = await witHttpClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(query);

if (queryResult.WorkItems.Any())
{
    foreach (WorkItemReference child in queryResult.WorkItems)
    {
         //do something
    }
}
```

I am forced each time to ask the TFS by id for get WorkItem and this is very long time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your answer, but i found this way.

I just use `WorkItemTrackingHttpClient.GetWorkItemsAsync(ids, expand: WorkItemExpand.Relations)` method and get all children WorkItems. It is fast enough for my.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query string to this:

```
Select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State] From WorkItemLinks where (Source.[System.TeamProject] = 'TeamProject' and [System.Id] IN ({ids})) and ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward') and (Target.[System.TeamProject] = 'TeamProject' and Target.[System.WorkItemType] <> '') order by [System.Id] mode (MustContain)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using work item query language (WIQL) to dynamically create a query in your code. Running a query is a two step process.

1. Find the query id for a given project and query path (example:
   Shared Queries/Current Iteration/Open User Stories).
2. Use the query id from step 1 and execute it to get the results.
   These results **only contain a limited reference back to the work
   items.**
3. Use the query result to get the **expanded** the work items

It's not able to get the TFS work items and his children WorkItems(not WorkItemReference) in one trip from TFS. The linked workitems will not expanded automatically in parent work item. Fore more details please refer below tutorials:

- [Query Work Items with WIQL](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/samples#query-work-items-with-wiql)
- [Get a list of work items with links and attachments](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#with-links-and-attachments)
- [Get a work item fully expanded](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#fully-expanded)