# Query in TFS of 3 diferent Work items ( chaild\ parent\ related )

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

i have two different trees ( parent \ child reltionships )
and i have "Related" relation between them.
for example:

1) First tree:

-Title

--Sub Title ( child of title ) ( related to Sub name )

2) Second tree:

-Name

--Sub Name (child of name)( related to Sub title )

an addition i have Test Case that Reference to Sub Name

i have to create some query  for get this results :

-Test Case

--Sub Name ( chaild of Name )( that Reference by Test Case )

---Sub Title ( related to Sub Name )

it is possible ? How  i can to do it ? thanks you very match !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be achieved by creating a basic query in TFS directly.

To view nested work items, tree queries are used by selecting the **Tree of Work Items query** type.

Tree queries are used to execute following tasks:

- Viewing the hierarchy
- Finding parent or child work items
- Changing the tree hierarchy
- Exporting the tree view to Microsoft Excel for either bulk updates to
  column fields or to change the tree hierarchy

To use ["Work Item and Direct Links" query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/using-queries?view=vsts&tabs=new-query-exp#use-direct-links-to-view-dependencies), you could only get  one level linked work item, such as  Test case--Sub Name or Sub Name --Sub Title.

To achieve what you need, you may have to use API and WIQL. How to use them, a sample for your reference: [Retrieving work items and their linked work items in a single query using the TFS APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748412/retrieving-work-items-and-their-linked-work-items-in-a-single-query-using-the-tf)