# Get User Stories with more than 5 Bugs in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I want to select user stories with more than 5 bugs as children. 
Using below query I can get user stories with at least one bug but filtering out the ones with less than 5 I'm lost.

[image]

How can I do this? Or is there any other way I can get this output? i.e: TFS extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no build-in feature to count/filter linked work item's count of a specific work item type.

As a workaround, you could export tfs query results to Excel and manage the results in excel side. With the help of excel, you should be able to filter out those work items you needs.

Another way is using TFS API to get the work items and their linked work items with bug type, finally count the number of linked  work items. About how to use API, please take a look at this related question: [Retrieving work items and their linked work items in a single query using the TFS APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748412/retrieving-work-items-and-their-linked-work-items-in-a-single-query-using-the-tf)

Answer (score 0):

You can use in the query in "Related Link Count" field:

[image]

Comment: This will return the user story which linked count >5(include all kind of work items) , not only linked bug >5.